# Page Switcher using the url (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to switch pages depending on the url using javascript?

I am currently working on a large scale site which requires a switcher to be added so that users can switch between specific market sites depending if the page which they are viewing is available on the other market.

What i exactly want is to be able to give the user the option to view the same page but on another market and if the page does not exist e.g. 400 page to redirect to that specific markets homepage.

Does anyone know if this functionality is possible using javascript?

Kind Regards,

B

Comment: please specify and give some code examplke what you want to achieve

Comment: yeah it will be easier to help with some more specific scenarios and if possible examples

Comment: it sounds like you want to have these sites exist in frames.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a link checker basically, which checks if the "page" on the other market is valid (does not redirect to homepage), and give the user the option to go to that page if it is valid?

I suppose this could be done using ajax. You would attempt to follow the link using ajax, and if the response is that of the homepage, you don't show the link, otherwise you show the link.

in jquery (roughly):

```
$.ajax({
 url:[your link],
 dataType:'html',
 success: function(html){
  if($(html).find("body.homepage").length == 0) 
   alert('link was good');
  else
   alert('link was bad');
 }
});
```

you might also be able to do it in a way that you could catch the 301/302 status from the redirect, which would be more efficient. But, I'm not sure exactly how to set that up. You would basically tell it not to redirect for the ajax call, and the 301/302 would show up as an error, which you could then check for the status 301/302.

Comment: Is it possible to give an example of this as im a beginner in javascript